# Properties of a Definite Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If you have an integral

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 6 +\frac{dz}{dx}$$

And the limits are:
At $x=0, y=y1, z = z1$, and at $x=x1,y=y2,z=z2$. Which when integrating gives:

$$\int_0^{x1}\frac{dy}{dx} dx= \int_0^{x1}6dx +\int_0^{x1}\frac{dz}{dx}dx$$

What happens to the limits of the 3rd term when cancelling the '$dx$'. Is it:

$$\int_0^{x1}\frac{dy}{dx} dx= \int_0^{x1}6dx +\int_0^{x1}dz$$

Or this:

$$\int_0^{x1}\frac{dy}{dx} dx= \int_0^{x1}6dx +\int_{z1}^{z2}dz$$

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The second one is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper and lower integration limits are:

$$\text{At $\color{blue}{x=0}$:} \quad y=y_1,\color{blue}{z=z_1},$$
$$\text{At $\color{blue}{x=x_1}$:} \quad y=y_2,\color{blue}{z=z_2}.$$

Therefore when you cancel the $dx$ term the integral is with respect to $dz$. The lower limit of integration changes from $x=0$ to $z=z_1$ while the upper limit of integration changes from $x=x_1$ to $z=z_2$.

$$\int_0^{x_1}\frac{dy}{dx} \,dx= \int_0^{x_1}6\,dx +\int_{\color{blue}{z_1}}^{\color{blue}{z_2}}dz$$

Answer (score 0):

Rather than think about cancelling $dx$ in the first and last integrals, remember that the integral of the derivative of, say, $f(x) $ is  just $ f(x) $,
$$ \int_a^b  \frac{d }{dx}f(x) ~~ dx = \big[ f(x) \big]_a^b ~~ . $$
Working with that form should straighten make clear which of the two options is right.